# SingalR2 / WCF Service to run continuously windows service

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, wcf, signalr

Please help me to take critical design decision. It looks like wide discussion but this is the basic question for any developer or designer to know can we create SingalR as windows service and how.
There is no where discussed , clearly documented or mentioned whether SingalR can be used in below scenario. I hope this question will help not only me but also loads of developers and designers.

In SingnalR , how can we create a service , which runs continuously to get Market prices from Fix connection, so when ever a client connect it updates prices to that client for any changes. any number of clients can connect to this service.

So how can we create SingalR as a windows service running continuously , updates to clients seamlessly parallel

UI will be in WPF , ASP.Net MVC for web , HTML5 Mobile

For this does SingnalR2 is the best one or WCF is the best option

Thanks,
ineffablep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you can use Hubs and signalR as windows service http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server

In the `OnConnected()` event, that happens when a client is logged in to you singnalR server, notify all client already connected on the change of stock price

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    // Get stock price 

   // Update client on new stocks
   Clients.All.UpdateStocks();
}
```

And your clients need to implement UpdateStocks(), see here how to create your client http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client